# How to export here maps to image file for printing programmatically?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

Just like leaflet and Arcgis JS Api have support for printing and exporting map to image files, how to do it in here maps? I explored here API and searched web but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a look at our Map Image REST API.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-image/topics/what-is.html

> **What Is the Map Image API?**
>   The HERE Map Image API is a REST API that allows you to request static map images for all regions in the world. The map images show conventional map views, but can also include points of interest, routes (for example, with turning points and junction views), statistics and heat maps.
>
> In addition, the API offers a variety of supplementary services for displaying location-based data. For example, it is possible to present roadsigns.

You can also request the map images in different formats:

> - 0 PNG
> - 1 JPEG (default)
> - 2 GIF
> - 3 BMP
> - 4 PNG8 
>     -5 SVG (only for companylogo)
>
> If this is not given, JPEG is used as default.

Within JavaScript, you can configure a MapTileService to request tiles of the map.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-service-maptileservice.html

Comment: So if the user has drawn something over map or map has other layers on in then this is not going to solve the problem. We are looking for something which exports whole map canvas into image for printing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a capturing functionality in HERE javascript API.

I made a quick draft how you can easily export the captured canvas element of the map with anything rendered on top of it:

```
// overlay element containing captured canvas element
var captureBackground = document.createElement('div'),
    bgStyle = captureBackground.style;

bgStyle.width='100%'; 
bgStyle.position='absolute'; 
bgStyle.top='0';
bgStyle.bottom='0'; 
bgStyle.background='rgba(0,0,0,0.7)';
bgStyle.padding='30px';
bgStyle.zIndex=1000;
captureBackground.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.body.removeChild(this);
});


// capture the map:
map.capture(function(capturedCanvas) {
    // remove previously added canvas from the overlay
    captureBackground.innerHTML = '';               
    captureBackground.appendChild(capturedCanvas);
    document.body.appendChild(captureBackground);
}, [], 50, 50, 700, 700);
```

For more information see https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__capture

Comment: Hello @M Omayr, did my answer work for you? If yes, could you please mark it as a correct answer?